# Showing ProgressView during a search

Tags: swiftui, progressview

*NOTE: this question is not about how to use `.searchable` or how to filter a `List`.*

I am using the following view to search an external database:

```
struct SearchDatabaseView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching: Bool

    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var searchResults: [Record] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(searchResults, id: \.self) { record in
                /// display results here
            }
            .navigationTitle("Search Database")
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
            .overlay {
                if isSearching {
                    ProgressView("Searching Database...")
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .disableAutocorrection(true)

        .onSubmit(of: .search) {
            searchDatabase()
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works, except the progress view is not showing. I tried putting the `.overlay` modifier after `.onSubmit`, but still it doesn't show.

What am I missing, is that not the proper use of `isSearching` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, where two views are used (like the docs examples) to perform
the search and dismissal using `dismissSearch` and display the `ProgressView`.

This is just an example code, see the docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-search-interface-activation
for more comprehensive info and examples.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SearchDatabaseView()
    }
}

struct SearchDatabaseView: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ListView()
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .navigationTitle("Search Database")
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                // searchDatabase()
                print("----> onSubmit: \(searchText)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
    
    @State private var searchResults: [String] = ["a-record", "b-record", "c-record", "d-record"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(searchResults, id: \.self) { record in
            Text(record)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Done") {
                dismissSearch()
            }
                .overlay {
                    if isSearching {
                        ProgressView("Searching Database...")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

To cater for your new question, I would do away with the `isSearching` thing.
Use a "normal" variable and implement a simple but effective code structure, such as in this example code:

```
struct SearchDatabaseView: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var showSearching = false
    
    @State private var searchResults: [String] = ["a-record", "b-record", "c-record", "d-record"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(searchResults, id: \.self) { record in
                Text(record)
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("Done") {
                    showSearching = false
                }
                .overlay {
                    if showSearching {
                        ProgressView("Searching Database...")
                    }
                }
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .navigationTitle("Search Database")
                .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                    showSearching = true
                    // searchDatabase()
                    // simulation of searchDatabase(), could also pass showSearching to it
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        // .....
                        showSearching = false  // when finished searchDatabase()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - `ProgressView` is now visible, but immediately shows when `SearchDatabaseView ` becomes active. Is there a way to show it only after the user hits enter in the search bar?

Comment: updated my answer to cater for your new question. The example code shows a different approach to using the unwieldy `isSearching` thing.